# Requested Resource not available 404 error

Tags: java, spring, rest, spring-mvc

I am using Spring MVC for my project and when I  entered the following URI in the browser :
http://localhost:8080/basic-web-app-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT/rest/accounts/all 
and I expected to get a list of my accounts. 
However, I am getting a **404 resource not found error.** 
What am I doing wrong ?

My web.xml is as follows :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
 xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd" id="WebApp_ID" version="3.0">

   <context-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>classpath:mongo-context.xml</param-value>
    </context-param>

    <listener>
        <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
    </listener>
  <servlet>
    <servlet-name>customers</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
  </servlet>
  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>customers</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>

</web-app>
```

customers-servlet.xml is as follows:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-4.2.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-4.2.xsd">



    <!-- <context:component-scan base-package="com.sam.spring.web.rest.mvc" />-->
    <context:component-scan base-package="sam.core.services, sam.core.repositories, sam.core.model, sam.rest.mvc"></context:component-scan>
    <mvc:resources mapping="/app/**" location="/app/build/"></mvc:resources> 

    <!-- <context:component-scan base-package="com.sam.spring.web.core.services" />-->
<!--  <bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.support.ControllerClassNameHandlerMapping"/>   
    -->
    <bean id="jspViewResolver"
        class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
        <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/jsps/"></property>
        <property name="suffix" value=".jsp"></property>
    </bean>
    <!--<import resource="classpath:WEB-INF/mongo-context.xml"></import>-->
</beans>
```

Account Controller class is as follows :

```
  package sam.rest.mvc;

import java.math.BigInteger;
import java.net.URI;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;

import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.http.HttpHeaders;
import org.springframework.http.HttpStatus;
import org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PathVariable;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestBody;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestParam;

import sam.core.model.entities.Account;
import sam.core.services.AccountService;
import sam.core.services.exceptions.AccountExistsException;
import sam.rest.exceptions.ConflictException;
import sam.rest.mvc.resources.AccountListResource;
import sam.rest.mvc.resources.AccountResource;
import sam.rest.mvc.resources.asm.AccountListResourceAsm;
import sam.rest.mvc.resources.asm.AccountResourceAsm;

@Controller
@RequestMapping("/rest/accounts")
public class AccountController {

    private AccountService accountService;
    private static Logger mylogger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(AccountController.class);

    /*@Autowired*/
    /*public AccountController() {

    }*/

    @Autowired
    public AccountController(AccountService accountService) {
        this.accountService = accountService;
    }

    /*@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public ResponseEntity<Object> findAllAccounts(@RequestParam(value="email", required = false) String email) {
        ArrayList<Account> list = null;
        if(email == null) {
            Account account1 = new Account();
            account1.setEmail("porip@gmail.com");
            account1.setPassword("12345");
            accountService.createAccount(account1);
            list = accountService.findAllAccounts();
        } else {
            Account account = accountService.findAccount(email);
            if(account == null) {
                //list = new AccountList(new ArrayList<Account>());;
                list = new ArrayList<Account>();
            } else {
                list =  (ArrayList)Arrays.asList(account);
            }
        }
        AccountResource res = new AccountResourceAsm().toResource(list);
        //Account res = (Account) list.get(0);
        return new ResponseEntity<AccountListResource>(res, HttpStatus.OK);
        // return new ResponseEntity<Object>(res.toJSONString(list.get(0)), HttpStatus.OK);
    }*/

    @RequestMapping(value="/all",method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public ResponseEntity<Object> findAllAccounts(@RequestParam(value="email", required = false) String email) {
         List<Account> list = null;

        if(email == null) {
                list = accountService.findAllAccounts();
            } else {
                Account account = accountService.findAccount(email);
                if(account == null) {
                    list = new ArrayList<Account>();
                } else {
                    list = Arrays.asList(account);
                }
            }
           AccountListResource res = new AccountListResourceAsm().toResource(list);
           for(int j=0; j< res.getJsonObjectAccounts().size(); j++) {
               mylogger.info(res.getJsonObjectAccounts().get(j));

           }
            //return new ResponseEntity<AccountListResource>(res, HttpStatus.OK);
            return new ResponseEntity<Object>(res.getJsonObjectAccounts().get(0),HttpStatus.OK);
    }

    @RequestMapping(value="/add",method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public ResponseEntity<AccountResource> createAccount(
        @RequestBody AccountResource sentAccount) {
        System.out.println("Account is talking");
        try {
            Account createdAccount = accountService.createAccount(sentAccount
                    .toAccount());
            AccountResource res = new AccountResourceAsm()
                    .toResource(createdAccount);
            HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
            headers.setLocation(URI.create(res.getLink("self").getHref()));
            return new ResponseEntity<AccountResource>(res, headers,
                    HttpStatus.CREATED);
        } catch (AccountExistsException exception) {
            throw new ConflictException(exception);
        }
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "/{accountId}", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public ResponseEntity<AccountResource> getAccount(
            @PathVariable BigInteger accountId) {
        Account account = accountService.findAccount(accountId);
        mylogger.info("Works" + account.toString());
        if (account != null) {
            AccountResource res = new AccountResourceAsm().toResource(account);
            return new ResponseEntity<AccountResource>(res, HttpStatus.OK);
        } else {
            return new ResponseEntity<AccountResource>(HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND);
        }
    }


}
```

Comment: Your servlet is listening to `/` - can you confirm the context is correct? (i.e. go to tomcat's admin console and see where the app is deployed) - the admin console is usually under `http://localhost:8080/admin`

Comment: tomcat no longer supports the admin web console. What should I do then?

Comment: what version of tomcat are you using?  do you get any errors in the log files?

Comment: I am using tomcat 7. It has no errors in the logs. Just that it cannot find the resource when I hit this url. :(

Comment: try `http://{host}:{port}/manager/html` - (see docs: http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/manager-howto.html#Introduction) - In the logs, there should be either an indication that the application was deployed successfully (and it would likely give you an URL for the app) or that there was an error deploying the application (giving you some reasons why it was not deployed) - can you have a second look?

Comment: The url of the app in the http://{host}:{port}/manager/html path is "http:localhost:8080/basic-web-app-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT. Here it does load the index.jsp however, it cannot find the requestMappings for the "/rest/accounts/all" which are specified in the controller.

Comment: and your controller is auto-wired as defined in `customers-servlet.xml` right? but is this file included in your app context? by whom?

Comment: How should I find that out?

Comment: Isnt it a default for Spring to include the .xml files in the Web-INF on the classpath ?

Comment: Your application needs to add it in your appContext.xml file.  Basically, you need to tell the Spring framework that this file is part of your configuration/application.  How you do it depends on  how  you defined your application (check your web.xml file, it should reference a spring config file.  One of those files should have a reference to your config

Comment: No, it is not a default for spring to include all .xml files in the WEB-INF - only one (I forget the default name, something like app-context.xml, I believe) - you can instruct it to add more, but by default it will only look for the one (also depends on the version of spring)

Comment: Oh okies. Can you give me a configuration example ? I really appreciate your help.

Comment: I just noticed that your naming follows the `<application>-servlet.xml` pattern so it should be loaded - weird

Comment: yeah. exactly  :( It is getting loaded . Just that the request mapping isnt working. Like when I hit the url I get a mapping not found error.

Comment: can you try creating a method that takes no parameters (and print `hello world`) it could be that it cannot find a method that passes no parameters in the query string